# How does the light waves make up to my eye?

Tags: visible-light, waves

I was thinking about a situation were there is a group of people in a room. While all those people are observing something(none of them are blind) the light ways need to reach their respective eyes. But, how does the light ways make to one's eyes without being disturbed by the other light waves moving towards the eyes of others?

Even there are a million people in a room one can see everything clear. How is it possible?

Comment: Because electromagnetic waves add linearly.  Different waves can therefore travel thru the same space without effecting each other.

Answer (score 4):

Electromagnetic waves obey the [principle of superposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superposition_principle). In other words, the light waves pass right through each other. There are situations in which this is not the case. It's the same reason you can hear everyone.